# How to get improved editor for asking Stack Overflow question?

Tags: support, ask-question-wizard-2018

Whenever I ask questions on Stack Overflow I get one of two different "question editors":

One is the standard editor where you select all the different features you may want in your question. (images, italics, lists, etc.)

However, recently whenever I click "Ask Question", it brings me to a simplified version that walks you through the steps and lacks any buttons to add images and such. Instead, it has information about how to put them in manually at the top.

I don't know what causes which to be used, but the first one is obviously much easier to create questions.  For example, with the first one, you can drag and drop images instead of manually uploading to Imgur and linking.